# Ubuntu on Pixelbook

Tags: dual-boot

I'm running Ubuntu unity side by side on my Pixelbook and when I switch from Chrome into it I have zero functionality. Its just the blank orange and purple screen. I can't even open the terminal. Any ideas of why, and how to fix?